# Serenity Widget element in Kotlin

Tags: selenium, kotlin, serenity-bdd

We have JUnit Serenity project in kotlin for testing of mobile applications.

We are trying to create custom widget element, but we are half-way successful.

Implementation in java - working

```
@ImplementedBy(MyWidgetJImpl.class)
public interface MyWidgetJ extends WidgetObject {

    public void aaa();
}

public class MyWidgetJImpl extends WidgetObjectImpl implements MyWidgetJ {


    public MyWidgetJImpl(final PageObject page, final ElementLocator locator, final WebElement webElement, final long timeoutInMilliseconds) {
        super(page, locator, webElement, timeoutInMilliseconds);
    }

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='button_text_title']")
    private WebElementFacade title;

    @Override
    public void aaa() {
        System.out.println("*********************************" + title.getText());
    }
}
```

This element is correctly initialized in PageObject and title is printed.

Implementation in kotlin - not working

```
@ImplementedBy(MyWidgetKImpl::class)
interface MyWidgetK : WidgetObject {

    fun aaa()
}

class MyWidgetKImpl(page: PageObject, locator: ElementLocator, webElement: WebElement, timeOut: Long) : WidgetObjectImpl(page, locator, webElement, timeOut), MyWidgetK {

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='button_text_title']")
    private lateinit var title: WebElementFacade

    override fun aaa() {
        println("*********************************" + title.text)
    }
}
```

In this case we are not able to build the project. Build errors are:

> Error:(10, 1) Kotlin: MyWidgetKImpl inherits conflicting members:
>   public open fun waitUntilEnabled(): WebElementFacade! defined in
>   net.serenitybdd.core.pages.WidgetObjectImpl, public abstract fun  waitUntilEnabled(): T! defined in
>   xx.xx.mobile.framework.xxx.MyWidgetK

28 errors of functions/members from WebElementFacade/WebElementFacadeImpl.

Do you know how to properly implement custom serenity Widget in kotlin?

Or by any chance is there different way to create WebElements with custom functionality?

Comment: I'm not familiar with those annotations or what they do, but have you tried using ::class.java instead of just ::class? This is just a guess here.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer you question. If you can provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we should be able to guide you.